# click button from fragment to handle in other fragment

Tags: android, click, fragment, android-tabhost

I have fragment DashboardFragment is tabhost contain fragment  AllDeviceFragment [image]

back is button on DashboardFragment. 
(AllDeviceFragmen is tab)
AllDeviceFragment contain recycleview is list 
when I click to one Item it show another list then click on back button how to show old list. thank

DashboardFragment

public class DashboardFragment extends Fragment {

```
private FragmentTabHost mTabHost;
private ImageButton imbBack;
private ImageButton imbHome;
private TextView tvPositionName;
private String mPositionName;
SharedPreferences sp;
private int mPositionId;
public static final String SharePreDashBoard = "SharePreDashBoard";


// declare interface here to back press button click;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Log.d("Fragment 1", "onCreate");

   /* if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        mTabHost.setCurrentTabByTag(savedInstanceState.getString("tab"));
    }*/

    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(PositionFragment.SharePrePosition, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    mPositionName = sharedPreferences.getString("PositionName", "");
    // mPositionId = .getInt("POSITIONID",1);
}

public DashboardFragment() {
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    Log.d("Fragment 1", "onCreateView");


    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dashboard, container, false);

    imbBack = view.findViewById(R.id.imb_back);
    imbHome = view.findViewById(R.id.imb_home);
    tvPositionName = view.findViewById(R.id.tv_position_name);

    mTabHost = view.findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
    mTabHost.setup(this.getActivity(), getChildFragmentManager(), android.R.id.tabcontent);


    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("position_TAG").setIndicator("Location"),
            PositionFragment.class, null);

    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("device_TAG").setIndicator("Devices"),
            DeviceFragment.class, null);

    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("allDevice_TAG").setIndicator("All Devices"),
            AllDeviceFragment.class, null);

    /**
     *  set onClick for ImageButton Back*/

    imbBack.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            onClickBack();

        }
    });
```

AllDeviceFragment

public class AllDeviceFragment extends Fragment implements DeviceAdapter.OnItemClickListener, TestMuiltiAdapter.OnItemClickListenerDevice {

```
RecyclerView recyclerView;
SearchView searchView;
ArrayList<String> dataDevice;
private ArrayList<DataDevice> mDeviceList;
private ArrayList<Object> mIoList;

public static final String ShareDevice = "ShareDevice";

private DeviceAdapter deviceAdapter;
private TestMuiltiAdapter testAdapter;
private ApiInterface mApiService;
private SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
private String strTokent;
private ArrayList<Data> itemArrayList;

HashMap<String, Integer> hashMapDevice;
AdminAgentActivity mActivity;


@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    mActivity = (AdminAgentActivity) activity;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mApiService = ApiClient.getClient().create(ApiInterface.class);
    mDeviceList = new ArrayList<>();
    dataDevice = new ArrayList<>();
    hashMapDevice = new HashMap<>();
    itemArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    mIoList = new ArrayList<>();

    sharedPreferences = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(LoginActivity.MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    strTokent = sharedPreferences.getString("TOKEN", "");
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_all_device, container, false);

    recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclview_all_device);
    searchView = view.findViewById(R.id.sview_all_device);

    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
    deviceAdapter = new DeviceAdapter(mDeviceList, this);
    //     recyclerViewPosition.setAdapter(positionAdapter);

    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            final List<DataDevice> filteredModelList = filter(mDeviceList, newText);
            deviceAdapter.setFilter(filteredModelList);
            return true;
        }
    });

   // Call<Device> call = mApiService.getDeviceList2(strTokent, 2);
    Call<Device> call = mApiService.getDeviceList(strTokent);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<Device>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Device> call, Response<Device> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {

                dataDevice.clear();
                mDeviceList.clear();
                ArrayList<ItemsDevice> itemsDeviceArrayList = response.body().getDataDevice().getItemsDevices();

               /* add data to hashmap device*/
                for (int j = 0; j < itemsDeviceArrayList.size(); j++) {
                    String deviceName = itemsDeviceArrayList.get(j).getNameDevice();
                    int deviceId = itemsDeviceArrayList.get(j).getId();
                   // Message.message(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),String.valueOf(deviceId));

                    hashMapDevice.put(deviceName, deviceId);
                }
               /*add data to mdevicelist*/
                for (int i = 0; i < itemsDeviceArrayList.size(); i++) {
                    dataDevice.add(itemsDeviceArrayList.get(i).getNameDevice());
                }
                for (String strDevice : dataDevice) {

                    mDeviceList.add(new DataDevice(strDevice));
                }
                recyclerView.setAdapter(deviceAdapter);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Device> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });

    return view;
}

private List<DataDevice> filter(List<DataDevice> models, String query) {
    query = query.toLowerCase();

    final List<DataDevice> filteredModelList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (DataDevice model : models) {
        final String text = model.getStrNameDevice().toLowerCase();
        if (text.contains(query)) {
            filteredModelList.add(model);
        }
    }
    return filteredModelList;
}

@Override
public void onItemClick(int position) {

    testAdapter = new TestMuiltiAdapter(mIoList, this);

    String mDeviceName = "";
    int device_id = 1;
    try {
        mDeviceName = mDeviceList.get(position).getStrNameDevice();
        device_id = hashMapDevice.get(mDeviceName);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.getStackTrace();
    }

    mDeviceList.clear();

    Call<Io> call = mApiService.getIOList(strTokent, device_id);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<Io>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Io> call, Response<Io> response) {
            itemArrayList.clear();
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                mIoList.clear();

                itemArrayList = response.body().getData();

                for (int i = 0; i < itemArrayList.size(); i++) {
                    int dataType = itemArrayList.get(i).getData_type();
                    String nameIo = itemArrayList.get(i).getName();

                    if (dataType == 1) {
                        mIoList.add(new AnalogType(nameIo, itemArrayList.get(i).getCurrent_value()));
                    }
                    if (dataType == 2) {
                        mIoList.add(new DigitalType(nameIo));
                    }
                    if (dataType == 3) {
                        mIoList.add(new StringType(nameIo, itemArrayList.get(i).getCurrent_value()));
                    }
                    if (dataType == 4) {
                        mIoList.add(new MultiChoiceType(nameIo));
                    }
                }

                recyclerView.setAdapter(testAdapter);
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Io> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });

   /*Toast.makeText(getActivity(), mPosition, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    SharedPreferences sharePosition = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(SharePosition, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharePosition.edit();
    editor.putString("POSITION", mPosition);
    editor.commit();
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.fragment_container_device, new DeviceOfPositionFragment())

            .commit();*/
}
```

}

adapter

public class DeviceAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {

```
private List<DataDevice> deviceList = new ArrayList<>();


private OnItemClickListener mListener;


public interface OnItemClickListener {
    void onItemClick(int position1);
}

public DeviceAdapter(List<DataDevice> deviceList, OnItemClickListener mListener) {
    this.deviceList = deviceList;
    this.mListener = mListener;
}

@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.list_position_row, parent, false);
    return new MyViewHolder(view);

}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    DataDevice mDeviceList = deviceList.get(position);
    holder.tvListPosition.setText(mDeviceList.getStrNameDevice());
    holder.tvListPosition.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (mListener != null) {
                mListener.onItemClick(position);
            }

        }
    });


}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    if (deviceList == null) {
        return 0;
    } else
        return deviceList.size();
}

public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView tvListPosition;

    public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        tvListPosition = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.list_position);
    }
}

public void setFilter(List<DataDevice> devices) {
    deviceList = new ArrayList<>();
    deviceList.addAll(devices);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

}

Comment: Post your recyclerView Adapter code.

Comment: I have button on one fragmet how to click on it to control list recycleview on another fragment

Comment: You can create an interface and method for the button click. And implement the same interface in your fragment and override the button click method.

Comment: ok, i'll try. thank Archana